# Angular2 - Radio button value binding

Tags: html, forms, angular

I have a problem to bind the data from a group of radio buttons. What I want is to bind the visible value whenever I check one of the radio button. Can someone help me with this?

Thanks a lot!

```
<div class="col-lg-8 inputs-group">
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-primary active">
            <input type="radio" name="visible" [(ngModel)]="visible" autocomplete="off" value="true">Yes
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
            <input type="radio" name="visible" [(ngModel)]="visible" autocomplete="off" value="false">No
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand, you *have* already bound the visible variable (with value) from your radio button.

Comment: The problem is I cannot make any selection in the UI...

Comment: Works fine here: http://plnkr.co/edit/dXepezGd9TVFAxeItXga?p=preview could you reproduce issue in plunker?

Comment: `value="true"` binds the string `'true'` (and `'false'`). Try instead `[value]="true"`